# How to embed a reference in VS created exe?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, dll, mysql-connector

I'm using a mysql .NET Connector library (Mysql.Data) in my project. As far as I understand it, I only need to use the mysqldata.dll which is in the assemblies folder after the connector is installed. I'm going to be using the program on a computer that has .NET 2.0 but doesn't have the connector.

How do I add the .dll file to a project such that the dll is used internally - I hope that makes sense. If the program calls out to .NET to find it, (as it does) - the whole thing fails and errors out.

Comment: You should just be able to ship mysql.data with your app - it needs to be in the bin folder. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268924/running-a-built-net-application-which-required-mysql-data which appears to be a duplicate of your question.

Comment: You can use [ilmerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Solution Explorer, under your project, expand References, select the MySql.Data assembly, view the Properties for the assembly, and change **Copy Local to True**.  Now when you compile the project, MySql.Data.dll will be output to the bin directory.

(You will not embed one assembly into another.  Instead, you deploy the MySql.Data.dll along with everything else in your build output which is required.  This is simply known as adding a reference ... I don't think you really wanted to embed it.)

Comment: Awesome, I think that's what I need. Is there a way to merge that dll with the exe though, so that it's just one exe and no other files?

Comment: Yes, but that's very atypical, and whether it's legal depends on the license of third-party library.  There's no good reason to do that.